# OnKey Event For One EditText Is Working For Two EditTexts, How To Fix This?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext

A beginner here, I am looking to make a simple app in which there are 4 sequential EditTexts, and as soon as the first EditText is completed and the user presses 'enter', the focus is automatically taken to the next EditText and the first EditText disappears.
I have used an 'onKey listener'. However, whenever the enter key is pressed for the first EditText, both the first and second EditText fields disappear.
Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText ko = findViewById(R.id.one);
    final EditText ma = findViewById(R.id.two);
    final EditText ko1 = findViewById(R.id.three);
    final EditText xa = findViewById(R.id.four);
    final TextView te = findViewById(R.id.ko);
    ko.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if(i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                ko.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                ma.requestFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    ma.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent k) {
            if(i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                ma.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                ko1.requestFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    ko1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent t) {
            if(i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                ko1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                xa.requestFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


}
public void onClick(View v){
    EditText ko = findViewById(R.id.one);
    EditText ma = findViewById(R.id.two);
    EditText ko1 = findViewById(R.id.three);
    EditText xa = findViewById(R.id.four);
    String t = ko.getText().toString();
    String u = ma.getText().toString();
    String x = ko1.getText().toString();
    String w = xa.getText().toString();
    String total = t +" "+ u +" "+x + " " +w;
    Toast.makeText(this, total,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

}

Comment: You should return true after request foucs()

Answer (score 0):

The event will continue to bubble up the container chain if you return false

Returns True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.

```
    ko.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if(i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    ko.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    ma.requestFocus();
                }
                return true;//change this line and all its occurances
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Return true after requesting focus. Refer [View.OnKeyListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener)

> True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.

```
 public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if(i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                ko.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                ma.requestFocus();
                return true; // this will consume the Enter event
            }
            return false;
        }
```